# execute main through if condition in python

Tags: python

I have a python script in which there is a line:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
```

So how can I run this portion of the code in another script after importing the script above?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it just executed right away?

Comment: The script imported is usually defines functions and classes, you'd better not put it under the if.

Answer (score 10):

Make it an independent function.

```
def run_main():
    ....

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_main()
```

And you can call `run_main()` from another file.

Comment: I don't have the luxury of modifying the original file. Does it mean I will have to write a same function in my own code to do it?

Comment: Probably. Unless the file gives you some alternate way, but it sounds like it doesn't. There was a [suggestion to make it possible to run such code in included files](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0299/) but it was rejected a long time ago.